# Custom input range slider gets stuck after input

Tags: javascript, css, input, slider, range

I'm trying to have an input type = range slider that can indicate a price range. I also wanted to make it so i could have ticks on each option, but i guess that's for another question.

So far, I've been able to create and slightly style my slider and the CSS and JS to have it automatically update to fill the background behind it, and output.

However, now after having the output change based on an if statement, it updates exactly how I want it to! Once.... Then it breaks and doesn't allow any more updates. (The problem i'm sure is in my if statement function oninput)

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");

output.innerHTML = '200k-';


slider.oninput = function() {
  if (this.value = 0) {
    output.innerHTML = '200k-';
  } else if (this.value = 1) {
    output.innerHTML = '200k-400k';
  } else if (this.value = 2) {
    output.innerHTML = '400k-600k';
  } else if (this.value = 3) {
    output.innerHTML = '600k-800k';
  } else if (this.value = 4) {
    output.innerHTML = '800k-1m';
  } else if (this.value = 5) {
    output.innerHTML = '1m-2m';
  } else if (this.value = 6) {
    output.innerHTML = '2m+';
  }
}

var start_value = slider.getAttribute("value");

var x = start_value;
var color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117)' + (100 / 6) * x + '% , rgb(214, 214, 214)' + (100 / 6) * x + '%)';
slider.style.background = color;

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  x = slider.value;
  color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117)' + (100 / 6) * x + '% , rgb(214, 214, 214)' + (100 / 6) * x + '%)';
  slider.style.background = color;
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(117, 252, 117);
}

h1 {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

p {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

p span {
  color: rgb(117, 252, 117);
}

.slideContainer {
  width: 75%;
  align-self: center;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117) 5%, rgb(214, 214, 214) 0%);
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Worth?</h1>
  <div class="slideContainer">
    <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="6" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the double equals (==) operator to compare the values. Single equals is used for assigning values to the left hand side.

```
  if (this.value == 0) {
    output.innerHTML = '';
  } else if (this.value == 1) {
    output.innerHTML = '200k-400k';
  } else if (this.value == 2) {
    output.innerHTML = '400k-600k';
  } else if (this.value == 3) {
    output.innerHTML = '600k-800k';
  } else if (this.value == 4) {
    output.innerHTML = '800k-1m';
  } else if (this.value == 5) {
    output.innerHTML = '1m-2m';
  } else if (this.value == 6) {
    output.innerHTML = '2m+';
  }
}
```

**Complete Code:**

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");


slider.oninput = function() {

  if (this.value == 0) {
    output.innerHTML = '';
  } else if (this.value == 1) {
    output.innerHTML = '200k-400k';
  } else if (this.value == 2) {
    output.innerHTML = '400k-600k';
  } else if (this.value == 3) {
    output.innerHTML = '600k-800k';
  } else if (this.value == 4) {
    output.innerHTML = '800k-1m';
  } else if (this.value == 5) {
    output.innerHTML = '1m-2m';
  } else if (this.value == 6) {
    output.innerHTML = '2m+';
  }
}

var start_value = slider.getAttribute("value");

var x = start_value;
var color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117)' + (100 / 6) * x + '% , rgb(214, 214, 214)' + (100 / 6) * x + '%)';
slider.style.background = color;

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  x = slider.value;
  color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117)' + (100 / 6) * x + '% , rgb(214, 214, 214)' + (100 / 6) * x + '%)';
  slider.style.background = color;
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(117, 252, 117);
}

h1 {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

p {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

p span {
  color: rgb(117, 252, 117);
}

.slideContainer {
  width: 75%;
  align-self: center;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(117, 252, 117) 5%, rgb(214, 214, 214) 0%);
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Worth?</h1>
  <div class="slideContainer">
    <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="6" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
  </div>
</div>
```